# How to check if Twitter Bootstrap plugins are loaded successfully?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, plugins

I am new to Twitter Bootstrap. I am working on a webpage. It works fine when I use Bootstrap CDN. When I remove the Bootstrap CDN and try to use Twitter Bootstrap plugin, it seems unable to access the Bootstrap plugin. The webpage becomes a blank page where only words are displayed.

I have two questions here:

1. How to check if I have installed the Twitter Bootstrap plugin successfully. [Here](https://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap) is the link I have followed to install it. I also follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md) provided on the webpage.
2. How to check if the Twitter Bootstrap plugin is loaded successfully?

Here is the HTML code in my sample. 
**It works partially (some parts are working) when i remove the comment for meta name="layout"**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Comment Home</title>
  <!--meta name="layout" content="main"/-->
  <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"--> 
 </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Online Library System</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Kowledge is everything!</h1>
        <p class="lead">For the new member please sign up today to get the privilledge.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h4>Top book</h4>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
           <table class="table">
            <tr>
             <td>
              <g:img dir="images" file="index.jpeg" width="110" height="140px"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <g:img dir="images" file="index2.jpeg" width="110" height="140px"/>
             </td>
             <td>
              <g:img dir="images" file="index3.jpeg" width="110" height="140px"/>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           
           
           
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
          </div>          
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h4>Regulation & Rules</h4>
          <p>Penalty charges will be required upon any overdue. </p>
          <p><i> *Charges will be diffence based on the book access level.</i></p>
          <hr>
          <h4>Operating Day</h4>
          <p>Monday - Sunday : 8:00AM to 10:00PM</p>
          <hr>

          <h4>Address</h4>
          <p>Perpustakaan Negara Malaysia (Ibu Pejabat)</p>
      <p>232, Jalan Tun Razak,</p>
      <p>50572 Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia.</p>
   
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.gsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>  
  <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>       
  <g:layoutHead/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><asset:image src="grails_logo.png" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
  <g:layoutBody/>
  
  <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
  <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the web developer tools, check the `console` if your document connected correctly.

Comment: obviously check at console. right click inspect element.

Comment: if there is no error meaning that you already use the bootstrap (y)

Comment: I checked. It does not show any css.
However, when i remove the comment for <meta name="layout"> line. Some part of the webpage is working, but not entirely working.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your `main.gsp` so we can see how you are including all the bootstrap assets.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, I have included my <code>main.gsp</code>. Thanks in advanced for helping.